# Can anyone find equivalent c# code

Tags: c#

i need equivalent c# code

```
VssSdkClientId VSS_SDK_SPEC startVssSdkClientEcho(const VssSdkXChar *host,
                                                      const VssSdkPort port,
                                                      NotifyFunc &notifyFunc,
                                                      const eProtocolType protocolType,
                                                      bool doIcmpEchoRequest = true );
```

this is my c++ SDK code .... here i need to import this interface and need to perform some operation

```
[DllImport("VssSdkd")]
  public static extern void startVssSdkClientEcho(StringBuilder IpAddress, long port, ? ,eProtocolType proType, bool Req);
```

NotifyFunc &notifyFunc -> here  i need to implemet the some callback function it should call the function like

```
myNotifyFunc( enumType notificationType, void *data)
{

}
```

in c# "void *data" is not avalable how can achive this... hepl me guys... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a call back function you can pass in a reference to a delegate and P/Invoke will marshal the callback to your delegate.  See the this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx#pinvoke_registeringcallback).

For the void* parameter that would be best translated to an IntPtr which is always the same size as a pointer.  If you need to retrieve the data from that pointer you can use one of the methods in [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx).

So for your example:

```
public delegate void NotifyFunc(enumType notificationType, IntPtr data);

[DllImport("VssSdkd")]
public static extern void startVssSdkClientEcho(string IpAddress,
    long port, NotifyFunc notifyFunc, eProtocolType proType, bool Req);
```

Note that IpAddress can be a string.  It would only have to be a StringBuilder if the calling code modified it and passed it back.  Since the C++ prototype lists it as a const char*, it won't be changing the string.

Comment: hi shf301.....
 NotifyFunc callc=new NotifyFunc(Callbackas);  this is dele

startVssSdkClientEcho(0.0.0.0, 00, callc, siss, false); this is calling fun

Callbackas(eNotificationType type, IntPtr data){}  this is my called fun

is it correct it's giving some error msg

Comment: This is My Error

run time check failure #0 - the value if ESP was not properly saved across a 
function call. this is usually a result of
calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a 
different calling convention

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert when it comes to C++ interop, so I can't answer your question directly.  However, I suggest you have a look at [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net).  There are lots of examples of the correct way to use the Windows API from managed code.  That may be enough information to help you figure out what would be appropriate for your function.